# Twitter bootstrap spans in dynamic websites

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How am I supposed to generate dynamic rows with a CMS like WordPress?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6"></div>
  <div class="span6"></div>
  <div class="span6"></div>
  <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
```

That doesnt work.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6"></div>
  <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6"></div>
  <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
```

This works but how am I supposed to program the back-end for the rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm, you don't have nearly enough description of what you are trying to do, so I'll assume you are looping through posts, and have them all stored in the `$posts` variable, and that the html is in the `content` property of each `$post`this is basically the only direction I can give you:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($posts as $post):
    if ($i%2==0) echo '<div class="row-fluid">';
      echo '<div class="span6">'. $post->content .'</div>';
    if ($i%2==1) echo '</div>';
    $i++;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Dave this is exactly the kind of logic I had to program, thank you very much! It is really annoying because if instead of row-fluid you use row you can just create a span4 div each time and it falls without flaws but if you use row-fluid you need to add a row each time

Comment: Cool.  I see you're new to the site, you should accept the answer if it told you what you needed to know.  Thanks!

Comment: What about an rowset that has 3 items?

Comment: This wouldn't work... `1 % 2 = 1` the second iteration would leave `<div class="span6">...</div>` without a parent `.row-fluid` div...

Answer (score 4):

K.I.S.S es

```
/**
 * Le rows to walk
 */
$rows = array(
    "Can",
    "I",
    "Has",
    "Cheezburger",
    "?"
);

/**
 * Le columns numbers
 */
$columns = 2;
/**
 * Le template for each row
 */
$rowTemplate = '<div class="row-fluid">%s</div>';
/**
 * Look at that function, yeah, it's a freaking cool function, it will chunk your array.
 */
$chuncked = array_chunk($rows, $columns);
/**
 * Foreach for make cool and magical stuffs
 */
foreach($chuncked as $chunk){
    $temp = array();
    foreach($chunk as $string){
        $temp[] = sprintf('<div class="span6">%s</div>', $string);
    }
    printf($rowTemplate,implode(null, $temp)). PHP_EOL;
}
```