# Bootstrap span4 dynamic content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble working with dynamic content which need to get span4 classes. Because a row can be max 12 columns so next 'article' need to jump to the next row.

Please check out this preview what I mean: http://www.dreamix-studio.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_q_2.jpg

```
  <div class="row-fluid"> 

           <div class="span12">

               <h2>TITLE</h2>

               <p>DESCRIPTION</p>

           </div>

  </div> 



  <div class="row-fluid">


           <!-- what should be dynamic -->

           <div class="span4">              


                <h2>TITLE</h2>
                <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn">BUTTON</a></p>


           </div>

            <!-- END dynamic -->


   </div>
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: if using php make it dynamic like... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427962/twitter-bootstrap-spans-in-dynamic-websites

Comment: or you can refer to this also... https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3494

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try This

```
  <div class="row-fluid"> 

           <div class="span12">

               <h2>TITLE</h2>

               <p>DESCRIPTION</p>

           </div>

  </div> 
  <div class="row">


           <!-- what should be dynamic -->

           <div class="span4">              


                <h2>TITLE</h2>
                <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn">BUTTON</a></p>


           </div>

           <div class="span4">              


                <h2>TITLE</h2>
                <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn">BUTTON</a></p>


           </div>


           <div class="span4">              


                <h2>TITLE</h2>
                <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn">BUTTON</a></p>


           </div>


           <div class="span4">              


                <h2>TITLE</h2>
                <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn">BUTTON</a></p>


           </div>


           <div class="span4">              


                <h2>TITLE</h2>
                <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn">BUTTON</a></p>


           </div>

            <!-- END dynamic -->


   </div>
```