# Bootstrap grid and layout output

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

Suppose that I have a block of HTML:

```
 <figure>
     <img/>
 </figure>
```

and I need to wrap them in Twitter Bootstrap 3 columns, like `<div class="col-md-3">{content}</div>`. I need to make rows every 4 times in the loop (to sum the 12 columns fitting the row) to make the grid.

How is the best way to achieve this?

Does Twig offer that solution easily? I would like to just pass what the each column classes I need and the "function" work out to split the columns automagically.

I'm using https://stackoverflow.com/a/16428403/1110456 as a solution, but seems that has a better way to do that. I currently use CakePHP and a framework and PHP language.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try something like this. It will:

- Get a count of how many objects you have in your view
- Set the object counter and column counter to zero
- If this is your first column, start a `<div class="row">`
- Display the content
- Increment the column counter by one
- If this is column 4, or if this is your final item, close the row div
  and reset the column counter.

  ```
  $count = count($models);
  $i = 0;
  $column = 0;

  foreach ($models as $model) { 
      if ($column == 0) {
          echo "<div class='row'>";
      }

      echo "<div class='col-md-3'>" . "Content" . "</div>"; 

      $column = $column + 1;

      if((++$i === $count && $column !== 4) || ($column == 4)) {
          echo "</div>";
          $column = 0;            
      }
  }
  ```